# warning (hpack filter): error: ...xmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/fontloader-20 21-01-07.lua:24653: stack overflow

Tags: overflow

I have a `main.tex` document in which I include the contents of 30 `.tex` files; the final document is supposed to have a total of 30 chapters.  Each chapter is around 10-15 pages long, so it is quite a lengthy document.

I execute `lualatex -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape --enable-write18 main.tex` from the Linux command line to compile my `.pdf` document.

I can successfully compile up to ~22 chapters (i.e. when I comment out the other 8 chapters in the `main.tex` file).  But I just cannot get ***all*** 30 chapters to be compiled - please see the error message it gives below.  I have ruled out the possibility that there is a bug in one of the 30 chapters.  Each chapter compiles successfully when I comment out the remainder of the chapters.

It has become clear to me that this error message is dependent on the "volume of all the contents together", and not the content/syntax of the chapters itself.  But that is as far as my understanding goes, however.  Does anyone know what exactly this error message means?  **More importantly, is there a solution that mitigates this error?  Please help, anyone.**

*If you'd like, I can add you as a collaborator on my (private) GitHub repository of this LaTeX project so that you can have a deeper look at what might be the root of the problem.*

```
warning  (hpack filter): error: ...xmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/fontloader-20
21-01-07.lua:24653: stack overflow

.
<to be read again>
\ltj@@reset@badness
l.375 \end{comps}


warning  (hpack filter): error: ...xmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/fontloader-20
21-01-07.lua:24482: stack overflow

.
<to be read again>
\ltj@@reset@badness
l.379 \end{remglyph}


warning  (hpack filter): error: ...xmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/fontloader-20
21-01-07.lua:24482: stack overflow

.
<template> \endtemplate

l.379 \end{remglyph}


warning  (hpack filter): error: ...xmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/fontloader-20
21-01-07.lua:24868: stack overflow

.
<to be read again>
\ltj@@reset@badness
l.379 \end{remglyph}


warning  (hpack filter): error: ...xmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/fontloader-20
21-01-07.lua:24868: stack overflow

.
<template> \endtemplate

l.379 \end{remglyph}


warning  (node filter): error: ...xmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/fontloader-202
1-01-07.lua:35032: stack overflow

.
<recently read> \endgraf

l.379 \end{remglyph}


warning  (hpack filter): error: ...xmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/fontloader-20
21-01-07.lua:35032: stack overflow

.
<to be read again>
\ltj@@reset@badness
l.379 \end{remglyph}


warning  (hpack filter): error: ...020/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfl
oad-szss.lua:48: stack overflow

.
<to be read again>
\ltj@@reset@badness
l.379 \end{remglyph}


warning  (hpack filter): error: ...020/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfl
oad-szss.lua:48: stack overflow

.
<template> \endtemplate

l.379 \end{remglyph}


warning  (hpack filter): error: ...020/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfl
oad-szss.lua:48: stack overflow

.
<to be read again>
\ltj@@reset@badness
l.379 \end{remglyph}


warning  (hpack filter): error: ...ve/2020/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/ltj-d
irection.lua:516: stack overflow

.
<to be read again>
\ltj@@reset@badness
l.379 \end{remglyph}


warning  (hpack filter): error: ...live/2020/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/ltj
-jfmglue.lua:1311: stack overflow

.
<to be read again>
\ltj@@reset@badness
l.379 \end{remglyph}


warning  (hpack filter): error: ...xmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/fontloader-20
21-01-07.lua:34923: stack overflow

.
<to be read again>
\ltj@@reset@badness
l.379 \end{remglyph}


warning  (hpack filter): error: ...xmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/fontloader-20
21-01-07.lua:35101: stack overflow

.
<to be read again>
\ltj@@reset@badness
l.379 \end{remglyph}


warning  (hpack filter): error: ...xmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/fontloader-20
21-01-07.lua:35101: stack overflow

.
<to be read again>
\ltj@@reset@badness
l.379 \end{remglyph}


warning  (mlist to hlist): error: ...ve/2020/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/ltj
-charrange.lua:83: stack overflow
.
\remcom #1->$\lceil $
                     #1$\rfloor $
l.379 \end{remglyph}
```

Answer (score 1):

I get such an overflow with this document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luatexja}

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_step_inline:nn{1000}
{
  \int_step_inline:nn {500} %works with 200
   {\hbox{blub}\space } \par
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

```
warning  (hpack filter): error: ...stall/tex/latex-dev/luaotfload/fontloader-202
2-06-15.lua:25611: stack overflow

.
<to be read again> 
\ltj@@reset@badness 
l.92 }
```

I assume that you have many boxes in your document too. Report this to the luatexja maintainer.

Comment: Can you perhaps advise on how to consult the luatexja maintainer?  My search resulted in a dead end...

Comment: the ctan page shows the bug tracker https://ctan.org/pkg/luatexja